# Convert from one type to another based on input

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a proxy between two networks.  I want to do something like:

```cpp
void onMsg(std::string topic, Msg msg) {
  if (topic == "topic1") {
    InMsg1 inmsg1 = parseMsg1<InMsg1>(msg);
    OutMsg1 outmsg1 = convert(inmsg1);
    publish<OutMsg1>(topic, outmsg1);
  }
  // repeat for each message type we need to convert.
```

So I can't use templates because the types depend on the topic.  It would be nice if I could create a map with something like the following and just have it look it up.  (I know I can't use types in maps, just an example.)

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::pair<Type1, Type2>> _map = {
  { "topic1", { InMsg1, OutMsg1 } },
  { "topic2", { InMsg2, OutMsg2 } },
  { "topic3", { InMsg3, OutMsg3 } }
}
```

Anyone have suggestions or at least some type of design pattern I can look at?

For reference, I'm converting from MQTT to ROS messages.  So I need to parse the MQTT message based on the topic the message was received on, and then publish on the same topic on the ROS side.

Comment: to be honest I didn't quite understand the types problem.. but here's something you can do: use a map to std::variant. and check the variable type at run time. or build a super class and derive your types from it.

Comment: You could use polymorphism.  Just create a `MessageTranslator` class and subclass it for each different kind of message.  Then map from topics to the appropriate translator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is for: representing values of a known set of types.

Your incoming message is an `std::variant<mqtt::type1, mqtt::type2, ...>`.  Your outgoing message is an `std::variant<ROS::type1, ROS::type2, ...>`.  Converting from one to the other should be done by [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

```
using Incoming = std::variant<type1, type2, ...>;

// converting from mqtt to 'internal' type using
// template specialization
template<T> T parseMqtt(const mqttmsg &msg);
type1 parseMqtt<type1>(const mqttmsg &msg) {
  return {...};
}
type2 parseMqtt<type2>(const mqttmsg &msg) {
  return {...};
}
// dispatch using a type identifier
Incoming parseMqtt(const std::string &topic, const mqttmsg &msg) {
  ...
  if(topic == "topic 1") { return parseMqtt<type1>(msg); }
  if(topic == "topic 2") { return parseMqtt<type2>(msg); }
  ...
}

// converting from 'internal' type to ROS using
// overloads:
ros_message to_ros_msg(const type1 &msg) {
  return {...};
}
ros_message to_ros_msg(const type2 &msg) {
  return {...};
}

// bringing it all together
auto mqtt_to_ros(const std::string &topic, const mqttmsg &msg) {
  const auto &incoming = parseMqtt(topic, msg);
  const auto &outgoing = std::visit(
     [](const auto &msg) { return to_ros_msg(msg); }
     , incoming);
  ros_send(outgoing);
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing now.  I was wondering if there was a way to do it without having to add a block for each section (parseMQTT, to_ros_msg, if topic == "", etc each time I add a new topic.  But it doesn't seem like there is a nice way to do that right now.

Answer (score 1):

First, extract the proxy logic into a template function:

```
template <class InMsg, class OutMsg>
void proxy(std::string topic, Msg msg) {
    InMsg inmsg = parseMsg<InMsg>(msg);
    OutMsg outmsg = convert<InMsg, OutMsg>(inmsg);
    publish<OutMsg>(topic, outmsg);
}
```

Now you can create a dispatch table that contains handlers:

```
using ProxyHandler = std::function<void(std::string, Msg)>;
std::map<std::string, ProxyHandler> handlers = {
    { "topic1", &proxy<InMsg1, OutMsg1> },
};
```

And use it like so:

```
auto it = handlers.find(topic);
if (it != handlers.end()) {
    (it->second)(topic, msg);
}
// or
handlers[topic](topic, msg);
```